# Как подключить кусок JSON в PYTHON, VIBER BOT API

Tags: python, json, viber, viber-api

Возможно это максимально глупый вопрос, который вы когда либо видели, но у меня вопроc

```
{
  ...    
  "ActionType": "share-phone",
  "ActionBody": "reply",
  "Text": "Зарегистрироваться"
}
```

Я использую библиотеку VIBER BOT API, и у меня вопрос, как подключить тот кусок JSON кода к пайтон.

Не совсем понимаю как это делается, готов к гноблению и унижению в коментариях, понимаю что это неизбежно в случае с моим вопросом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте код или дайте больше информации, чтобы понять, что значит "подключить". Если это значит "обработать", то в python есть такая библиотека, которая работает из коробки `json`.

```py
import json
# обычно, но не правило, json который прилетает в Python - это строка или битовая последовательность, поэтому ваш кусок json отправлю в переменную как строку
initital_json = '{"ActionType": "share-phone","ActionBody": "reply","Text": "Зарегистрироваться"}'
```

Для Python, json преобразуется в словарь, который понятен Python. [Документация](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html). В документации описаны сущности, которые могут быть изменены, например, `true` в json заменяется на `True` в Python.

Теперь сделаем наш json (строка в python) понятным для python словарем:

```py
from_json_to_dict = json.loads(initital_json)
print(type(from_json_to_dict))

# Out
# <class 'dict'>
```

Вот теперь, можно обращаться к словарю в Python

```
print(from_json_to_dict.get("ActionType"))

# Out
# share-phone
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь)